# Electron webview tag does not execute callback after executing JavaScript (CoffeeScript)

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, electron

I have a webview tag, and I'm trying to execute javscript and read the result, as per the docs: [Electron webview tag docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-view-tag.md#webviewexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture-callback). However the callback is never executed:

```
@webviewOutlet.executeJavaScript("10+2", (n)-> console.log "#{n}") #Nothing in console
```

I'm using the WebView in NodeJS as part of an Atom package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is missing required parameter `userGesture` and as a result, you passing function where expected boolean variable.

Try this:

```
@webviewOutlet.executeJavaScript("10+2", false, (n)-> console.log "#{n}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter for the `executeJavaScript` function is not the callback, it is the `userGesture`.

The correct way to use this function is the following:

```
webview.executeJavaScript('10 + 2', false, (n) => { console.log(n) })
```

Of course, change the second parameter `userGesture` to your needs.

[Documentation](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-view-tag/#webviewexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture-callback)